# Tree-cutting quota: where to check?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

My barony has been scolded by a Elf Diplomat:

> You have disrespected the trees in this area, but this is what we have come to expect from your stunted kind. Further abuse cannot be tolerated. Let this be a warning to you.

Now it seems that Woodcutters are not cutting any wood anymore, and I really need to make more beds for my 150 people population. Most of them still have to lay on dirty ground!

So: where can I check my quota to see if I have no remaining trees left for cutting this year?

P.S.: elves made an ambush right now around my Fortress. They seem to be pissed off with me.

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Comment: Maybe I just don't have axes to cut wood? I can't find them on `Stocks`, under `Tools` nor under `Weapons`. Am I looking at the wrong places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amount of trees felled and limits should be visible on World screen under Civilisations tab. When you hover over civilisations, there are agreements under Imports/Offering lines. It usually says *"You have no agreements with this land"*, and any agreements (like trade requests, tree felling quota, etc) will appear there.

Comment: I have checked now my Civilisations tab, and found that I have no tree-cutting agreements. Maybe my problem is, then, that I have only 3 copper battle axes for 200 dwarves, and not even by selecting all of them to be woodcutters they are able to find these 3 axes?

Comment: I just found out that my Squads took the axes as their weapons. I had to exclude the axes from the squads to allow them to be used to fell trees.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah another thing is that tree quota is not actually enforced in your fort. It is up to you to not designate excess tree-cutting jobs.